# Center footer on wordpress theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, footer

I'm currently creating a website and use the really nice Reykjavik theme. First of all, I created a child theme. Now, I would like to do some modifications on child theme.
In this template it is possible to personnalise the footer, but not to change it's position. I provide to check it's position with the page inspector, but don't find anything...

[image: site-info]

I provide to modify my style.css child theme adding relative position to the footer but it doesn't change anything..

[image: Css modification]

Do you have any idea on how to center the footer text please ?

Thank you very much :)

Jerry

Comment: You currently have span which is an inline element.
Add display: block; and text-align: center; This should help.

Comment: Thank you for your help @GrzegorzT. ! I tried to modify style.css file as you said, so without position: relative but with display: block; and text-align: center; but it does'nt change anything :(

Comment: I did not notice the span closing before Test Ⓒ 2019 :)
The class you need to handle is **site-info**. There, add a text-center and it's best to show what this class has inside.

Comment: @GrzegorzT. Yes it's part of site-info :) But it's not to put in the style.css file ?

Comment: @GrzegorzT. PS : I edited my post ; is it not because the frame for the text is too little ?

Comment: Last chance ;)
I downloaded the Reykjavik theme locally and it looks like this. I added `margin: auto` to the **site-info** and it worked, all text in the element is centered.

Comment: @GrzegorzT. Thank you very luch for your help :) I tried to add  `$site_info_text='<p style="margin: auto;">test</p>' ;` in the **site-info** file just previous the  `echo $site_info_text;` but it doesn't center my text :( I do any mistake ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We add margin to the site-info class: auto then the text is centered.

```
.site-info { margin: auto }
```

[image: Reykjavik]

Answer (score 0):

## If you are centering a block-element

This is if you are trying to center a `<div>`, `<img>`, etc.
[W3Schools list of inline and block elements](https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_blocks.asp)

You may want to consider using `margin: 0 auto;`

```css
.centered {
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*margin:0 auto: this gives the element a 0 top and bottom margin, and automatically sets the left and right to the maximum it can be*/
  width:100px;
  /*You need to specify a width for this to work*/
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="centered">
    Hello World
  </p>
</div>
```

## If you are centering an Inline element

For inline elements, like `<span>`, `<img>`, or text elements
[W3Schools list of inline and block elements](https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_blocks.asp)

For this, you can just use `text-align:center;`

```css
.centered {
  text-align: center;
  /*Just tell the text to center itself in the element*/
}
```

```html
<p class="centered">
  Hello World!
</p>
```

## Sources

[W3Schools list of inline and block elements](https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_blocks.asp)
[CSS Tricks: Centering in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

Comment: Thank you Ronan ! I tried to add the text align code but doesn't work... Is it not because the frame for the text would be too little ?