# Forcing to center footer doesn't make it

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a footer I want to center and having this code with CSS:

```
.footer {
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(42,53,65,1) 0%, rgba(0,67,121,1) 150%); 
    padding:20px;
    z-index: 70;
    font-size:9px;

    margin: 0 auto !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    text-align: center !important;  
    
    border: 0.1em dotted red;
}   
.fullWidthFooter, .fullWidthFooter#nav {
    width: 100% !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    
    border: 0.1em dotted brown;
}
#menu-footer-menu, #menu-footer-menu-footer-links-english { 
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    text-align: center !important; 
    width: 900px important;
    
    border: 0.1em dotted yellow;
}
#menu-footer-menu ul {
    display: inline-block;
    
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    text-align: center !important;
}   
    
<footer class="footer">
    <div id="inner-footer" class="row">
        ::before
        <div class="fullWidthFooter">
            <nav role="navigation">
                <ul id="menu-footer-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-339" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-339">....</li>
                    <li id="menu-item-336" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-336">....</li>
                    <li id="menu-item-343" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-343">....</li>
                    <li id="menu-item-349" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-349">....</li>
                </ul>                           
            </nav>
        </div>  
    </div>
</footer>
```

as you can see in CSS I try to force to show it centered but it doesn't and it remains at left, as you can see in the screenshot:

[image]

maybe forcing with 0 value is not the right way?...
I thought it was the right way after following what it's said here in the comment: [Center footer on wordpress theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57844003/center-footer-on-wordpress-theme)

A direction would be appreciated, thanks! Cheers!

Comment: What's definitively not the right way to _ask_, is to show only snippets that appear to not be able to reproduce what your screenshots shows in the first place (https://jsfiddle.net/2h5etms3/) - _proper_ [mre], please, when you ask this kind of question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I could understand your question, you need to center the div with yellow border.

**1)** For this, you need to remove the width property applied at `#menu-footer-menu, #menu-footer-menu-footer-links-english` and hopefully, it'd work for you.

**2)** Second approach you can use is to apply these properties to the above selector.

```
    display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
```

The code formatter isn't working, don't know why. But I guess you've got my point.

Comment: thank you for your direction!!!.... applying a different display was the trick... didn't thought about that because it's an horizontal menu and I thought it could broke horizontal placement of the `<ul><li>` list but indeed it worked! Thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you...